# Retrieve the recently added data from sqlite database android

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm storing song info(name, artist name, duration etc) in sql database in android app. I am able to feed the data to the database without any problems. So if I play 2 songs, song A first and song B after that. Both these are added to the database in the order they were played. 1st row- song A, second row - song B. What i want is , I want to retrieve the data in the opposite direction. I mean, when i display the songs, song B should come first and then song A. I know I have to use order by for this, but I can't figure out how.

Code:

Retrieve code:

```
  public ArrayList<SongInfoModel> getRecentlyPlayed(){

    ArrayList<SongInfoModel> rpList = new ArrayList<>();
    String selectQuery  = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME ;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery,null);
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){

        do{

            long id = cursor.getLong(0);
            String SongName = cursor.getString(1);
            String artistName = cursor.getString(2);
            long dur = cursor.getLong(3);
            String Art = cursor.getString(4);

            SongInfoModel sh = new SongInfoModel(id,SongName,artistName,dur,null,Art);

            rpList.add(sh);
        }while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    return rpList;
 }
```

Code to create table:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {

    String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME+ "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
            + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_ARTIST + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_DURATION + " INTEGER,"
            + KEY_ART + " TEXT"
            + ");";

    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);

}
```

Comment: Can you also provide the create table statement in your question? This will help me and others give you the correct answer (which should be something like add ` ORDER BY id` to your select sql statement

Comment: Updated the code!

Answer (score 0):

You can insert also a counter with each row and just select them ordered by the counter in descending order.

Comment: Only alter these:`String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME+ "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
            + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_ARTIST + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_DURATION + " INTEGER,"
            + KEY_ART + " TEXT, "
            + "count INTEGER"
            + ");";` and then your sql statement like `String selectQuery  = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " order by counter desc";`

Comment: How to increment the counter? I have hard code d the value for count but how to extract it from the user?

Comment: `if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
int counter = 1;
        do{

            long id = cursor.getLong(0);
            String SongName = cursor.getString(1);
            String artistName = cursor.getString(2);
            long dur = cursor.getLong(3);
            String Art = cursor.getString(4);

            SongInfoModel sh = new SongInfoModel(id,SongName,artistName,dur,null,Art, counter);
counter++;
            rpList.add(sh);
        }while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }` obviously you'll ahve to add the int counter into your song model